# Why does the ebay sandbox OAuth application token generation fail to grant enough permissions even when granted the correct scope?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ebay-api

tried multiple options to get application token for connecting Ebay Rest APIs.

ending up with an issue while generating token or permission issues while invoking ebay APIs.

## Tried with both sandbox and default api.ebay.com auth_cope as below:

Try 1:
`grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.inventory https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.account https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.fulfillment https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.finances https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.item.draft https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.payment.dispute https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.item https:%3A%2F%2api.sandbox.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.reputation`

Try 2:
`grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope https:%3A%2F%2api.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.inventory https:%3A%2F%2api.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.account https:%3A%2F%2api.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.fulfillment`

> All three approaches gives the token, but fails when createOrReplaceInventoryItem API, below is the response

`Reason: {"errors":[{"errorId":1100,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Access denied","longMessage":"Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."}]}`

## Tried with the following request and not able to generate the token:

Try 3:
`grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope%2Fsell.inventory  https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope%2Fsell.account https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope%2Fsell.fulfillment`

> failed to get the access token with below message.

`{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or exceeds the scope granted to the client"}`